# OpenBSD ftp-proxy behind NAT itself

Tags: ftp, nat, openbsd, pf

Is it possible to change the PASV IP ftp-proxy of OpenBSD sends to clients, without changing the listen address of redirection control (`-b <address>`)?

I have the following setup:

```
FTP client --> 1:1 NAT router --> OpenBSD router --> FTP server
```

The *1:1 NAT router* has a NAT rule to forward everything to the *OpenBSD router*, the OpenBSD router runs the `ftp-proxy -R <FTP server IP>`. When the FTP client sends the PASV command, the proxy answers with the *Entering Passive Mode (227)* message with his own source IP on the interface to the *1:1 NAT router* (obviously). Since the *1:1 NAT router* is not protocol aware, it forwards this message and the client receives the message with the PASV IP of the *OpenBSD router*, which it does not have a route to.

Is there a way, that I can tell ftp-proxy to send the *Entering Passive Mode* message with a different source IP?

Answer (score 1):

man ftp-proxy

```
-a address
    The proxy will use this as the source address for the control
    connection to a server.
```